# Share a secondary x axis between multpile subplots within a loop

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am adding subplots to a figure within a loop and can't seem to get the secondary x axis to show up correctly. Is there anything like a sharex for secondary axes?

```
n = len(tempfig11.axes)
for i in range(n):
    tempfig11.axes[i].change_geometry(n+1, 1, i+1)                                              

# Add the new subplot
tempaxes11 = tempfig11.add_subplot(n+1, 1, n+1, sharex = tempaxes11, sharey = tempaxes11)
tempaxes11.set_xlabel('Range (nmi)')
tempaxes11.set_ylabel('SNR')
tempaxesSecond11.set_xlabel('Range (km)')
tempaxes11.xaxis.get_major_ticks():
tick.label1.set_fontsize(9)
for tick in tempaxes11.yaxis.get_major_ticks():
     tick.label1.set_fontsize(9)
for tick in tempaxesSecond11.xaxis.get_major_ticks():
     tick.label1.set_fontsize(9)
bolMade11 = True
tempaxes11.scatter(prngNM,psnr,s=markersize,c=str(rgbColor),zorder=2,label=str(rlt),marker='o',edgecolors='none')
tempaxesSecond11.scatter(prngK,psnr, alpha = 0)
bolFirstSubPlot11 = False
```

EDIT: looking into it further the problem seems to be in the loop where I am changing the geometry.  For some reason it will change the geometry of everything except the secondary axis.  Anyone know how to access the secondary access so I can change its geometry?

EDIT: I figured out the problem.  In my change geometry loop when I get n = len(figure.axes) I needed to subtract 1 from this number or otherwise it would move the secondary axis off the chart.

Comment: Please consider posting a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get faster/better answers.

Comment: I'm with @Sait on this one. I don't understand what you are trying to do with your code. Can you provide either a code that can be executed, or better explain / draw the result that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi, sorry I haven't had time to provide a code that can be executed and my script is way too long to post.  I was trying to add pictures to explain but it wouldn't let me.  I figured it out though.  Thanks!